Keycloak with Google IDP how do I get more user data like birthday, gender or address?
Im using keycloak and configuring google as an identity provider is working fine. So if I perform sign up with google its working and the user is created in Keycloak.
Now I would like to have an easier onboarding for the user. Therefore I would like to get more data from the user automatically e.g. Birthdate, Address, Gender when the user registers because it is required for the app to work.
I found this document: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes with all google scopes for oauth provided by google.
So i added the scopes into my identity provider:

This is the string inside Scopes
openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read

And google does automatically show in the onboarding process that the app is asking for permission to see the requested private data:

So from my understanding Google should send the data like gender in the request to keycloak and I just have to user a mapper to map it to the user.

Since it was not working I did some research and I figured out the google is not sending the data directly. Instead adding scopes in keycloak only give the gathered access token the permission to use the corresponding API's. In this example the "People API". I activated the API in the google cloud but still no user attribute with gender in keycloak. Do I now have to create a small webserver that is using the access token to send a request to the people's API? I feel like this should be possible from within Keycloak so I assume I miss something. And if not what would be the best practice and are there any guides? Because I didnt find a lot regarding this topic.
